# How to loop script till user input is empty?

Tags: shell, loops, while-loop, csh

I am trying to make my script to repeat till the user leaves the block question empty. I just got the loop to run, but I can not find a way to make it possible to stop it when block is empty.

I hope some one can help me!!

```
#!/bin/tcsh -f
#

set word="start"
until ($word !=""); do

#First ask for Compound and Block Name.
echo -n "please enter block name: "
read block
echo -n "please enter compound name: "
read compound

#Now coping template with new name
#
cp Template $block
#
        for line  in `cat $block`;do
        echo $line | sed -e "s/test1/${block}/g" -e "s/test2/${compound}/g" >>./tmp124.txt
done

mv ./tmp124.txt $block

done
```

Comment: Please, ALWAYS show the error message!  Why make us guess?

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. My error is: syntax error at line 20: 'end of file' unexpected.

Answer (score 3):

Do you want to use bash or csh? You are using bash syntax but tagged your question csh and call tcsh in the first line of your code.

To answer your question, here are examples of how to iterate on standard input until some input is empty:

For tcsh:

```
#!/bin/tcsh

while ( 1 )
    set word = "$<"
    if ( "$word" == "" ) then
        break
    endif

    # rest of code...
end
```

For bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read word; do
    if [ -z $word ]; then
        break
    fi

    # rest of code...
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Use "**Until do**" loop,

**Eg :**

*For session variable i am assigning default value, Then entering loop. User can pass any value on each prompt when the value is empty, Loop will Terminate and exit the script.*

```
session="Mysession"

until [$session -eq $null]
do
    echo $session
    echo "Leave Blank to Terminate session"
    read -p "Enter session name : " session
done

 echo "Exiting.."
```